# How do I serve json data to a page in Golang?

Tags: jquery, json, go

It's not a matter of marshal or unmarshal, it's what do I need to write to my writer in combination with my Jquery?

Right now I have this for Go

```
func serveJson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params){
    j, _ := os.Open("adjs.json")

    defer j.Close()

    var obj respWords

    json.NewDecoder(j).Decode(&obj)
    js, _ := json.Marshal(obj)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    w.Write(js)
}
```

and this is my jquery getting the json

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function randomize() {
        scene = {}
        $.getJSON('adjs.json', function(scene){
           console.log('encoding')
        })
        console.log(scene)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

your async request does not save the data to the external variable, do your logic in the success function of your ajax request

```
$.getJSON('adjs.json', function(scene){
           console.log(scene);
           //do logic here with scene
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can serve a file containing JSON as follows:

```
func serveJson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params){
    j, err := os.Open("adjs.json")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
        return
    }
    defer j.Close(0
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    io.Copy(w, f)
}
```

There's no need to decode and encode the file.

You can also use [ServeFile](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeFile):

```
func serveJson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params){
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "adjs.json")
}
```